# Flutter'sTry Catch never works

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried everything.. I always have some problem with async try catch blocks..
I read the guide that flutter has on it but nothing there works.. i am trying to make http requests, but whenever there is a problem like (connection refused) it breaks the code. i tried:

```
 try {
      switch (type) {
        case RequestType.Get:
          response = await _httpClient
              .get(url, headers: headers)
              .catchError(catchError);
          break;
        case RequestType.Put:
          try {
            response = await _httpClient
               .put(url, body: body, headers: headers)
               .catchError(catchError);
          } catch (e) {
            catchError();
          }
          break;
        case RequestType.Post:
          response = await _httpClient
              .post(url, body: body, headers: headers)
              .catchError(catchError);
          break;
        default:
          return null;
          break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      catchError();
    }
```

I tried every combination there.. with async catchError only.. with try catch only.. with try catch above the switch, with try catch only on the http request.. NOTHING works.. How can this be done????

Comment: try removing all the try-catches and .catchErrors, except the most outer try-catch. Then test it with putting a print(e).

Comment: I tried it.. i put in the question just to see everuthing i tried, but i tried each individual block only and combinated

Answer (score 0):

Keep one `try...catch` for all, keep it simple:

```dart
Future doRequest(type, url, headers) async {
  try {
    switch (type) {
      case RequestType.Get: return await _httpClient.get(url, headers: headers);
      case RequestType.Put: return await _httpClient.put(url, body: body, headers: headers);
      case RequestType.Post: return await _httpClient.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    }
    throw('Method not supported');
  } catch (e) {
    // print exception to console 
    // or comment the line, if You don't care about error
    print(e.error); 
    return null;
  }
}
```

or avoid using `try...catch` in this logic and handle issue on higher level.

```
Future doRequest(type, url, headers) {
    switch (type) {
      case RequestType.Get: return _httpClient.get(url, headers: headers);
      case RequestType.Put: return _httpClient.put(url, body: body, headers: headers);
      case RequestType.Post: return _httpClient.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    }
    throw('Method not supported');
}

try {
  final response = await doRequest(RequestType.Get, "some/url/here", {});
  /* do something with response */
}
catch (error) {
  //handle error here
}
```